# Ajax event handler does not update variables?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, callback

I'm having issues getting a variable declared in an .click function to be updated in a Get function within the click function.  I've gathered that even though the variable has the same name, within the Get function it is really declaring it anew.

I've tried to find examples helping me, but it appears to me that the Get method is such a specialized function that the examples didn't seem to apply.

I would like the value of 'SettingContentToEdit' to get updated with information retrieved with the Get function.

Below is the code.

Thank you for your help!

```
 $(".cellSetting").click(function () {
          var clickedClass = $(this).attr("class");
          var clickedItemID = $(this).attr("id")
          var SettingContentToEdit = "not changed";

          var JSONSend = {
              'ItemName': clickedItemID,  //send the item name so the model knows which one to pull up!
              'ItemSetting': clickedClass
          };




          $.get(
                        '/Home/getItem',
                         JSONSend,
                          function (data) {

                              //  $('#dialog').html(data.ItemSettings[data.SettingToEdit]);

                              SettingContentToEdit = data.ItemSettings[data.SettingToEdit];

                              alert(SettingContentToEdit); //returns the correct info

                          }
                        );

          alert(SettingContentToEdit);  //returns "not changed"

});
```

Comment: Look up "asynchronous callbacks". The callback `function (data) {` has not run by the time the function `$.get` returns. There are a million duplicates on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of evaluation in JavaScript code using Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212736/order-of-evaluation-in-javascript-code-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your ajax call is asyncronous.  The success handler for the `get()` function is called some time after your click handler and the alert() has already completed.  You can refer to the local variables in your success handler, but the code that follows the success handler executes BEFORE the success handler does.

This is because your `get()` operate is asynchronous.  Calling it just STARTS the networking operation and then your javascript execution continues (while the networking operation works in the background).  After starting the networking operation, your `alert()` is called.  Then, some time LATER, the Ajax call completes and the success handler is executed.

This is a very common mistake and has indeed been asked and answered hundreds (if not thousands) of times here on SO (I've personally probably answered 20-30) so you are not alone in missing this understanding at first.

If you want to use the results of the ajax operation, then you need to put the code that does that either in your success handler or put it in a function that you call from your success handler.  You cannot put it after the `get()` function because it will execute too soon before the results are known.

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't immediately obvious what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. If you check `SettingContentToEdit` a second or so later than you are doing, you'd see the value has updated.

Either put your code inside the `get` function (where you have your alert showing the correct value) or make the request synchronous (you'll have to look up the jQuery docs because I don't use jQuery).